# CircleCI flutter orb unexpected argument: version

Tags: flutter, circleci, circleci-orb

I have strange error when executing CircleCI/flutter orb `flutter/install_sdk_and_pub` command with Flutter version argument:

`Error calling workflow: 'distribute'Error calling job: 'distribute'Error calling command: 'flutter/install_sdk_and_pub'Unexpected argument(s): version`

Full yaml file:

````
orbs:
  flutter: circleci/flutter@1.0.1
jobs:
  distribute:
    macos:
      xcode: 12.8.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - flutter/install_sdk_and_pub:
          version: 2.2.3
          app-dir: ./app
      - flutter/install_ios_pod:
          app-dir: ./app
      - flutter/install_ios_gem:
          app-dir: ./app
      - run:
          command: bundle exec fastlane ios distribute
          working_directory: ios
workflows:
  distribute:
    jobs:
      - distribute```
````

Answer (score 3):

Using `flutter_version` instead of `version` fixed the error:

```
- flutter/install_sdk_and_pub:
          flutter_version: 2.8.1
```